# BeautifulSoup duplicates value of previous attribute if attr for current element doesn’t exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

First time asking, so forgive me if this is a silly question, but I’ve spent several days on this and am stuck. I’m scraping info from a website that lists companies and for some (but not all) it includes additional attributes (i.e. its region). However, if a firm doesn’t have an attribute (i.e. region) it prints the value of the previous attribute. The csv file ends up looking like this:

1. Company1; description1, region1 (has this attribute)
2. Company2; description2, **region1** (doesn’t have attribute, so takes it from previous row)
3. Company3; description3, **region1** (doesn’t have attribute, so takes it from previous row)
4. Company4; description4, region4 (attribute appears again, prints correct value)

My code is below and any help would be greatly appreciated. I’ve tried using if/else and try/except to print "not found" or pass for missing attributes, but couldn’t get it to work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = 0
while page <= max_pages:
    url = 'https://websitename' + str(page) + '.html'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    page += 1
    with open('sample.csv', 'a') as file:
        for comp_desc in soup.findAll(attrs={'items'}):
            for head in comp_desc.find_all(attrs={'head'}):
                print(head.text)
            for info in comp_desc.find_all(attrs={'info'}):
                print(info.text)
            for region in comp_desc.find_all(attrs={'region'}):
                print(region.text)
            file.write(head.text + ';' + info.text + ';' + region.text + "\n")
    file.close()
```

UPD:

Adding code below stopped showing duplicate values, BUT now it writes everything, not just the name of the tag (value now prints this: a class="region" href="www">Region name /a>) and doesn't show "not found" for missing attributes.

```
for region in comp_desc:
    region = comp_desc.find('a',attrs={'class': 'region'})
        if region is not None:
            print(bregion.string)
        if not bregion:
            print("not found")
```

To write the info I changed it to this:

```
file.write(str(region) + ';' + head.text + ';' + info.text + '\n')
```

Tried doing region.string or region.text, but I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: `region` in `for region in ..` probably does not get overwritten if the `find_all` doesn't find anything. Instead of looping, you should explicitly be assigning something to `region`.

Comment: eg: `region_list = comp_desc.find_all(attr={'region'}); if not region_list: region = None` and then only `write` `region` if `region is not None`. Or something like that

Comment: deceze, Thank you for your quick reply! I'm just getting into Python and at this point I don't really understand how to put in code what you're saying.

Comment: @dwanderson. Thanks. I ran it, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide the sample HTML code and the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, thanks! Unfortunately, it's in an unpopular foreign language so I can't send a link, but I've updated the question as I have had some luck with stopping the duplicate values.